# Why has the edit button disappeared from my iPhone in Mail?

Tags: iphone

Up until I updated my iPhone a few days ago, I could go to "edit" in my email and "mark as unread" when I need to come back to the message later. This feature has disappeared. Is there anyway to get it back? How do I mark an email as unread?

Answer (score 3):

It has just moved to the Flag symbol in the bottom left hand corner.